# org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: Unsupported CSS selector '*[name='userName']'. Reason: 'Error: 'name' is not a valid attribute

Tags: java, android, selenium, testng, appium

i am trying to click an element but its throwing InvalidSelectorException.

These are my dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.7.1</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
            <version>4.7.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
            <version>8.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.javafaker</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafaker</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.7.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>7.6.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.10.1</version>
            <type>maven-plugin</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
            <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-testng</artifactId>
            <version>2.18.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.26</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20220320</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.9.1</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>7.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
            <version>7.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-deps</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.6</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

**This my runner class:
**

```
package mobilerunner;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;

import org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import commonuseractions.CommonActionMethods;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.options.UiAutomator2Options;
import io.appium.java_client.service.local.AppiumDriverLocalService;
import mobile_pageobjects.SauceLab.Login_Page;
import utils.DriverFactory;

public class SauceLab_Aroon extends CommonActionMethods{
    
    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUp() throws MalformedURLException {
        
        PropertyConfigurator.configure(configFilename);
        UiAutomator2Options opt = new UiAutomator2Options()
                .setApp("D:\\Mobile Automation\\APK\\Android.SauceLabs.Mobile.Sample.app.2.7.1.apk")
                .setAppActivity("com.swaglabsmobileapp.MainActivity")
                .setAppPackage("com.swaglabsmobileapp")
                .setAutomationName("UiAutomator2")
                .setDeviceName("Pixel 2 XL API 31")
                .eventTimings();
        appDriver = new AndroidDriver(new java.net.URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub/"),opt);
        DriverFactory.setDriver(appDriver);
    }

    @Test
    public void test1() throws Exception {
        new Login_Page().logIn();
    }
    
    @AfterClass
    public void tearDown() {
    }
}
```

**This my PageObject class:
**

```
package mobile_pageobjects.SauceLab;

import java.time.Duration;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.CacheLookup;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;

import commonuseractions.CommonActionMethods;
import io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AndroidFindBy;
import io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AppiumFieldDecorator;

public class Login_Page extends CommonActionMethods{
    
    @AndroidFindBy(accessibility =  "test-Username")
    @CacheLookup
    WebElement userName;
    
    
    public Login_Page() {
//      PageFactory.initElements(new AppiumFieldDecorator(appDriver,Duration.ofSeconds(15)), this);
        PageFactory.initElements(appDriver, this);
    }
    
    public void logIn() throws Exception {
        Thread.sleep(15000);
        clickMethod(userName," UserName input field ");
    }

}
```

**Here is the Exception printed in console.**

org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: Unsupported CSS selector '*[name='userName']'. Reason: 'Error: 'name' is not a valid attribute. Supported attributes are 'checkable, checked, clickable, enabled, focusable, focused, long-clickable, scrollable, selected, index, instance, description, resource-id, text, class-name, package-name''
For documentation on this error, please visit: https://selenium.dev/exceptions/#invalid_selector_exception
Build info: version: '4.7.1', revision: 'c6795baf1a3'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '17.0.3'
Driver info: io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver
Command: [d0d24b81-2280-4c6d-9692-afc0af6b9bf9, findElement {using=css selector, value=*[name='userName']}]
Capabilities {appium:app: D:\Mobile Automation\APK\An..., appium:appActivity: com.swaglabsmobileapp.MainA..., appium:appPackage: com.swaglabsmobileapp, appium:automationName: UiAutomator2, appium:databaseEnabled: false, appium:desired: {app: D:\Mobile Automation\APK\An..., appActivity: com.swaglabsmobileapp.MainA..., appPackage: com.swaglabsmobileapp, automationName: UiAutomator2, deviceName: Pixel 2 XL API 31, eventTimings: true, platformName: android}, appium:deviceApiLevel: 31, appium:deviceManufacturer: Google, appium:deviceModel: sdk_gphone64_x86_64, appium:deviceName: emulator-5554, appium:deviceScreenDensity: 560, appium:deviceScreenSize: 1440x2880, appium:deviceUDID: emulator-5554, appium:eventTimings: true, appium:javascriptEnabled: true, appium:locationContextEnabled: false, appium:networkConnectionEnabled: true, appium:pixelRatio: 3.5, appium:platformVersion: 12, appium:statBarHeight: 84, appium:takesScreenshot: true, appium:viewportRect: {height: 2628, left: 0, top: 84, width: 1440}, appium:warnings: {}, appium:webStorageEnabled: false, platformName: ANDROID}
Session ID: d0d24b81-2280-4c6d-9692-afc0af6b9bf9
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:200)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:133)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:53)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:184)
at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:262)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:551)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ElementLocation$ElementFinder$2.findElement(ElementLocation.java:162)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ElementLocation.findElement(ElementLocation.java:60)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:367)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:359)
at org.openqa.selenium.By$PreW3CLocator.findElement(By.java:429)
at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByName.findElement(By.java:238)
at org.openqa.selenium.support.ByIdOrName.findElement(ByIdOrName.java:50)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ElementLocation$ElementFinder$1.findElement(ElementLocation.java:136)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ElementLocation.findElement(ElementLocation.java:80)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:367)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:359)
at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.DefaultElementLocator.findElement(DefaultElementLocator.java:70)
at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.internal.LocatingElementHandler.invoke(LocatingElementHandler.java:39)
at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy20.click(Unknown Source)
at commonuseractions.CommonActionMethods.clickMethod(CommonActionMethods.java:145)
at mobile_pageobjects.SauceLab.Login_Page.logIn(Login_Page.java:27)
at mobilerunner.SauceLab_Aroon.test1(SauceLab_Aroon.java:38)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)

Comment: Am i missing something?

Comment: It works now after changing the selector like this ---- @CacheLookup
 @FindBy(xpath =  "//android.widget.EditText[@content-desc=\"test-Username\"]")
 WebElement userName;

Comment: Check the locator for 'userName', may be you mentioned the wrong type of locator, ex. - instead of XPath, you would've mentioned as CssSelector, check that.

Answer (score 0):

After making some changes to the selector it worked.

**here are the changes**

```
@CacheLookup
@FindBy(xpath =  "//android.widget.EditText[@content-desc=\"test-Username\"]")
WebElement userName;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).